# Creating a copy constructor with arguements for a class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I have created a simple class that takes an argument to the constructor as shown below.

```
class Jam
{
     int age;
     std::string name;
     Jam *jam;

     Jam(std::string argName) {
          name = argName;
     }
};
```

It takes the argument and initializes the `Jam`'s `name` to the parameter passed. The only problem is that I'd like to be able to pass another copy of `Jam` to the constructor so I can initialize its pointer to an existing class by copying the values. Normally in C++ you could specify `Jam *jam = new Jam(existingJam);` and it would be copied by default, but since I already have `std::string argName` as a parameter, it refuses to let me do this.

I read an article [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/2666/) that explains how to create your own copy constructor, but it is rather tedious and involves copying each class member individually which seems like it would not make much sense for a class with 10+ data members. Is there a better way to do this than initializing each member individually?

```
Jam::Jam(std::string argName, Jam *argJam)
{
     age = argJam->age;
     //etc...
}
```

Comment: that's not a copy constructor, it has an extra string argument.

Comment: How dies it refuse to let you do it? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

[*It's quite possible I don't understand what you're asking, but here goes...*]

The compiler provides a copy constructor if you don't write one yourself.  Its behaviour is to copy each member variable in turn.

Comment: which is might or might not what you want (`Jam *jam;` looks a bit suspicious)